# E0167 argument of type "CHAR *" is incompatible with parameter of type "const wchar_t *"

Tags: c++, winapi

I was writing a project that allows me to draw lines on a process, but I am getting 2 errors:

```
E0167: argument of type "CHAR *" is incompatible with parameter of type "const wchar_t *" 
C2664: 'int _wcsicmp(const wchar_t *,const wchar_t *)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'CHAR [260]' to 'const wchar_t *'
```

I've changed my project settings from Unicode to Multi-Byte. It fixes the issue, but after switching it gives me another error on another part of the code.

Here is the source:

```cpp
DWORD GetProcId(const wchar_t* procName)
{
    DWORD procId = 0;
    HANDLE hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);

    if (hSnap != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        
        PROCESSENTRY32 procEntry;
        procEntry.dwSize = sizeof(procEntry);

        if (Process32First(hSnap, &procEntry))
        {
            do
            {
                if (!_wcsicmp(procEntry.szExeFile, procName))
                {
                    procId = procEntry.th32ProcessID;
                    break;
                }
            } while (Process32Next(hSnap, &procEntry));
        }
    }
}

uintptr_t GetModuleBaseAddress(DWORD dwPid, const char* moduleName) {
    uintptr_t dwBase = 0;
    do {
        HANDLE hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE | TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32, dwPid);
        if (hSnapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) { continue; }
        MODULEENTRY32 ModuleEntry32;
        ModuleEntry32.dwSize = sizeof(MODULEENTRY32);
        if (Module32First(hSnapshot, &ModuleEntry32)) {
            do {
                if (!strcmp(ModuleEntry32.szModule, (LPSTR)moduleName)) {
                    dwBase = (DWORD)ModuleEntry32.modBaseAddr;
                    break;
                }
            } while (Module32Next(hSnapshot, &ModuleEntry32));
        }
        CloseHandle(hSnapshot);
    } while (!dwBase);
    return dwBase;
}
```

When the character set is on **Unicode**, the line `if (!_wcsicmp(procEntry.szExeFile, procName))` doesn't give me any errors. In `GetModuleBase()` however, `ModuleEntry32` in the line `if (!strcmp(ModuleEntry32.szModule, (LPSTR)moduleName))` gives me both errors shown above.

When I set the character set to Multi-Byte, the error switches to `procEntry` in line `if (!_wcsicmp(procEntry.szExeFile, procName))`.

I can't seem to figure out the issue. It keeps telling me `argument of type "CHAR *" is incompatible with parameter of type "const wchar_t*"`

Comment: Please add to the question your understanding of the difference between `char` and `wchar`.

Comment: To me it looks like the first function assumes unicode is enabled and the second assumes it is not.

Comment: [It’s okay to be contrary, but you need to be consistently contrary: Going against the ambient character set](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20211210-00/?p=106021). Other than that, I'm having a hard time understanding what *"draw lines on a process"* is supposed to mean.

Comment: Sorry, what I mean by that is that I am reading the memory of the process and using information from that process to draw lines on my screen using GDI/GDI+. Didn't really mean drawing on the process :D

Comment: Is there are issue if you make it use UNICODE for both functions? I mean use `uintptr_t GetModuleBaseAddress(DWORD dwPid, const wchar_t* moduleName) {` and change `if (!strcmp(ModuleEntry32.szModule, (LPSTR)moduleName)) {` to `if (!_wcsicmp(ModuleEntry32.szModule, moduleName)) {`

Answer (score 1):

First off, your `GetProcId()` is buggy.  It is leaking the snapshot `HANDLE`, and it is not actually `return`'ing the process ID.

That being said -

You are mixing `char`/`wchar_t` strings with `TCHAR` APIs in a way that they are not meant to be mixed.

When `UNICODE` is defined, `TCHAR` maps to `wchar_t`, `PROCESSENTRY32` maps to `PROCESSENTRY32W`, `Process32First()` maps to `Process32FirstW()`, etc.

Otherwise, when `UNICODE` is not defined, `TCHAR` maps to `char`, `PROCESSENTRY32` maps to `PROCESSENTRY32A`, `Process32First()` maps to `Process32FirstA()`, etc.

So, if you want to use the `TCHAR`-based Win32 API functions, you need to use `TCHAR` strings, and `TCHAR`-based string comparisons (ie, `_tcsicmp()`), eg:

```cpp
DWORD GetProcId(const TCHAR* procName)
{
    DWORD procId = 0;
    HANDLE hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);

    if (hSnap != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        
        PROCESSENTRY32 procEntry;
        procEntry.dwSize = sizeof(procEntry);

        if (Process32First(hSnap, &procEntry))
        {
            do
            {
                if (!_tcsicmp(procEntry.szExeFile, procName))
                {
                    procId = procEntry.th32ProcessID;
                    break;
                }
            } while (Process32Next(hSnap, &procEntry));
        }

        CloseHandle(hSnap);
    }

    return procId;
}

uintptr_t GetModuleBaseAddress(DWORD dwPid, const TCHAR* moduleName) {
    uintptr_t dwBase = 0;
    do {
        HANDLE hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE | TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32, dwPid);
        if (hSnapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) { continue; }
        MODULEENTRY32 ModuleEntry32;
        ModuleEntry32.dwSize = sizeof(MODULEENTRY32);
        if (Module32First(hSnapshot, &ModuleEntry32)) {
            do {
                if (!_tcsicmp(ModuleEntry32.szModule, moduleName)) {
                    dwBase = (DWORD)ModuleEntry32.modBaseAddr;
                    break;
                }
            } while (Module32Next(hSnapshot, &ModuleEntry32));
        }
        CloseHandle(hSnapshot);
    } while (!dwBase);
    return dwBase;
}
```

Otherwise, when using explicit `char`/`wchar_t` strings, you need to use the Unicode/ANSI APIs directly, eg:

```cpp
DWORD GetProcId(const wchar_t* procName)
{
    DWORD procId = 0;
    HANDLE hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);

    if (hSnap != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        
        PROCESSENTRY32W procEntry;
        procEntry.dwSize = sizeof(procEntry);

        if (Process32FirstW(hSnap, &procEntry))
        {
            do
            {
                if (!_wcsicmp(procEntry.szExeFile, procName))
                {
                    procId = procEntry.th32ProcessID;
                    break;
                }
            } while (Process32NextW(hSnap, &procEntry));
        }

        CloseHandle(hSnap);
    }

    return procId;
}

uintptr_t GetModuleBaseAddress(DWORD dwPid, const char* moduleName) {
    uintptr_t dwBase = 0;
    do {
        HANDLE hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE | TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32, dwPid);
        if (hSnapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) { continue; }
        MODULEENTRY32A ModuleEntry32;
        ModuleEntry32.dwSize = sizeof(MODULEENTRY32);
        if (Module32FirstA(hSnapshot, &ModuleEntry32)) {
            do {
                if (!strcmp(ModuleEntry32.szModule, moduleName)) {
                    dwBase = (DWORD)ModuleEntry32.modBaseAddr;
                    break;
                }
            } while (Module32NextA(hSnapshot, &ModuleEntry32));
        }
        CloseHandle(hSnapshot);
    } while (!dwBase);
    return dwBase;
}
```